# Converting Objective C blocks to Swift Closures

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I am simply trying to convert this Objective C block to swift but there seems to be a problem, I am unable to solve.

**Objective C - Works**

```
HNKGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *searchQuery = [HNKGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery sharedQuery];

[self.searchQuery fetchPlacesForSearchQuery:"API_KEY_HERE"                              
completion:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {


            }
        }];
```

**Swift - Gives error**

```
var searchQuery : HNKGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery  = HNKGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery.sharedQuery()

searchQuery.fetchPlacesForSearchQuery("API_KEY_HERE", completion: 
{(places:NSArray, error: NSError) -> Void in

    })
```

**Error:**

```
 Cannot invoke 'fetchPlacesForSearchQuery' with an argument list of type '(String, completion: (NSArray, NSError) -> Void)'
```

Comment: I bet one or more of those parameters is an optional.

Comment: try changing it to to `NSError?` and / or `NSArray?`

Comment: @luk2302 tried it. same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift bridges NSArray to [AnyObject], this is what you should put into the method signature.

```
(places:[AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void
```